# Figure caption behaves strangely while using babel with Thai language

Tags: luatex, captions, babel

I was trying to insert a figure using LuaTeX with babel. However, there is one problem that occurred at the figure name.

The problem showed up when I ran this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelprovide[main, import]{thai}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[%
    ItalicFont={Laksaman-Italic.otf},%
    BoldFont={Laksaman-Bold.otf},%
    BoldItalicFont={Laksaman-BoldItalic.otf},%
    Script=Thai,%
    WordSpace=1.25,%
    Ligatures=TeX%
]{Laksaman.otf}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

พิจารณารูปตัวอย่าง \ref{fig: example_image_a} ข้างล่างนี้
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{รูปที่ 1}
    \label{fig: example_image_a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result is shown below.
[image: The rendered file]

As you can see, the word "รูปที่" in the caption name is rendered incorrectly (red box) as compared to the correct word "รูปที่" in the green box.

So, can anyone please enlighten me why did this problem occur and also how to fix this problem?

Comment: try with Renderer=HarfBuzz in the font options. (I don't have font and can't try).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just have tried using the option `Renderer=HarfBuzz` in the font options. However, the problem still remains the same :(.

Comment: does your word work in normal text?

Comment: oh, sorry your problem is with the first word only. That is probably some babel error. I will check.

Comment: well  it looks quite deliberate.  If you think it is wrong you can open an issue at https://github.com/babel/babel/issues. Or you can redefine figurename, see the documenation how to do that.

Comment: I don't speak Thai but according to Google Translate the Babel default for figure is indeed wrong :) so opening an issue seems appropriate. Two other potential mistakes are "headto = เรยี น" and "proof = พิสจู น์", also "glossary" is untranslated.

Comment: It seems something went wrong in the conversion to Unicode. I’ll fix it, hopefully in time for TeXLive 2022.

Comment: Update: The issue is fixed when I edited the wrong captions in `babel-th.ini`. So it seems like the issue comes from that file. Thanks for everyone's help!